# How do I add an array of json objects in Karate API in a json file?

Tags: json, api, karate

In karate I can do the following in a feature file:

```
* def bars = { 'key': 'value' }
* def myJson = { 'foo': '#[] bars' }
```

In json files I can do the following:

```
{
   "foo": "#[] { "key": "value" }"
}
```

The aim is to only have to update json files when changes happen to the api.

So my question is how do would this be done in a **json file** when bars object has multiple key value pairs?
e.g.

Something like this:

```
{
  "foo": "#[] 
         { 
           "key": "value",
           "key1": "value",
           "key2": "value",
           "key3": "value",
           "key4": "value",
           "key5": "value",
           "key6": "value"
            ...
         }"
}
```

rather than this:

```
{
  "foo": "#[] {"key": "value", "key1": "value", "key2": "value", "key3": "value", "key4": "value", "key5": "value", "key6": "value" ... }"
}
```

Comment: you can't. not supported by karate. you are welcome to contribute code to make this possible